# How to use only if to make false

Tags: php

How can I do the following.

```
<?php if (is_mobile()) { ?>

<?php } else { ?>

<?php } ?>
```

I do not want to use an else, to hide something in the mobile version..

I've seen that in python something like `if not` ...but I do not know how I could do something like that in php

Comment: Using `!` will invert the return. `if (!is_mobile())`

Comment: @IsThisJavascript thanks :) I new in php

Comment: Or use `if (is_mobile() === false)` or `if (false === is_mobile())` ;p

Comment: or `if (is_mobile() !== true)`...